# Is there a Maven plugin listing all JUnit tests in a multi module project

Tags: maven, junit

Is there any maven plugin - or non-maven tool - out there which would browse a multi-modules project and return me a list of all existing JUnit testcases (ideally presented per module) in a usable form?

I want to be able to work on that list and distribute my tests across multiple hosts.
I checked surefire documentation and I'm surprised that it doesn't seem to be able to do that.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to write a script that reads the test names from the `target/surefire-reports` directories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a `.../target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile/default-testCompile/inputFiles.lst` in a Maven project.

You can use the [GMavenPlus Plugin](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus) and [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) to gather these files and put their content where you want.

Another option is to [develop an own Maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) that does the same.