# Maven - Get list of all tests without running them?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a maven project and I would like to get a list of all the test classes and their file paths, without having to execute all the tests.

After I run "mvn test", the only files that I have under target/ are

```
checkstyle-cachefile  checkstyle-checker.xml  checkstyle-result.xml  maven-shared-archive-resources
```

I want something very general, that doesn't require me to edit the pom.xml file.

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643420/is-there-a-maven-plugin-listing-all-junit-tests-in-a-multi-module-project

Answer (score 9):

In my case, the test classes names were stored in

```
target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile/default-testCompile/createdFiles.lst
```

You can run `mvn test-compile` to create it without running the tests.

Comment: while this is correct, it does a bad job for some cases. it included classes that are _not_ tests (some set-up that you might have in `src/test/java`), it included abstract classes (that of course are not tests) and are implemented by tests, it incorrectly parses nested classes. Overall, for a CI/CD pipeline, this is un-usable and parsing has to be done by hand.

Comment: In addition, it includes real tests that would not have ran